# Auto-Deploy to Google-Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Does anyone know a solution that allows me to auto-deploy to google-play whenever I launch a new version of an app?

The objective is to automate the process to have no human intervention.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gradle-play-publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher).

Add this to your gradle dependancies:

```
classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.0.2'
```

Set up your credentials

```
play {
    serviceAccountEmail = 'your-service-account-email'
    pk12File = file('key.p12')
}
```

And you can build and upload your apk using

```
gradlew publishRelease
```

Comment: pk12File = file('key.p12'). Where do you store the .p12 file? How does android access it?

Comment: The key.p12 (or keys.json) file is generated in the Play Store Console. It can be located anywhere on your filesystem. Android does not need this file, it is only used by the gradle plugin to authentication against the Play Store.

Comment: So when you write pk12File = file('key.p12'), how does gradle find key.p12 file? Can I give a path to the file on my file system?

Comment: Any ideas on how to use only the deploy functionality without the build?